# How to Move a Line Up or Down in Visual Studio Code on Chromebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, chromebook

I know how to do it on Mac, Linux and Windows, but it doesn't work on Chromebook. You'd expect it to be alt-up/down like Win/Linux, but that is treated like home and end.

Anybody know the trick?

Comment: Are you sure ? Can you go to `Selection -> Move Line Up` and read the shortcut next to that option ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Alt + Up/Down** and **Ctrl + Alt + Up/Down** are reserved by Chromebook. You could open **File --> Preferences --> Keyboard Shorcuts** in VS Code and change **Move Line Up/Down** settings to something else.

[Chromebook keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183101?hl=en)

[Chromebook keyboard shortcuts image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NscfI.png)

Comment: Thanks! Set them to ctrl+shift+UpArrow/DownArrow.

Answer (score 5):

There's a easy way.

Just open google-chrome and type **chrome://flags** in the URL bar,go to the Experiments page.

Search **Deprecate Alt based six-pack** , then **Enable** this feature.

Restart.

Then you can use the default shortcut to move line up/down in VSCode.

Comment: This should be the right answer. This removes some integrated shortcuts of the OS but helps to keep consistent keybindings using VSCode between Linux boxes. Thanks for sharing.